# How to add element to fetched data

Tags: php, api

I made a simple scipt that fetch the data from API. Evryhing works fine but I want to add arrows if the price difference is negative or positve.

Something like that:

+5,15 ⬆
-2,44 ⬇

Can someone give me a hint how to do that?  Thanks!

```
$url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,XRP,LTC,BCH&tsyms=USD&e=Bitstamp";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

// get btc price
echo "BTC: ";
echo "<span class='price'>";
echo $data['DISPLAY']['BTC']['USD']['PRICE'] . " ";
echo "</span>";

// get btc difference
echo "<span class='difference'>";
echo $data['DISPLAY']['BTC']['USD']['CHANGEPCT24HOUR'] . "%";
echo "</span>";

echo "<hr>";
```

Comment: your answer is too unclear. try to complete it please

Comment: answer or question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a check on the change to see if it's greater than one like so:

```
if($data['DISPLAY']['BTC']['USD']['CHANGEPCT24HOUR'] > 0){
    echo '⬆';
}else{
    echo '⬇';
}
```

the whole script looks like:

```
    $url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,XRP,LTC,BCH&tsyms=USD&e=Bitstamp";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

// get btc price
echo "BTC: ";
echo "<span class='price'>";
echo $data['DISPLAY']['BTC']['USD']['PRICE'] . " ";
echo "</span>";

// get btc difference
echo "<span class='difference'>";
if($data['DISPLAY']['BTC']['USD']['CHANGEPCT24HOUR'] > 0){
    echo '⬆';
}else{
    echo '⬇';
}
echo $data['DISPLAY']['BTC']['USD']['CHANGEPCT24HOUR'] . "%";
echo "</span>";

echo "<hr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$change = (float) $data['DISPLAY']['BTC']['USD']['CHANGEPCT24HOUR'];

$change_increased = $change > 0;
$change_decreased = $change < 0;

$change_increased 
  && print('+' . $change . '⬆');
$change_decreased 
  && print($change . '⬇');
```

I'm assuming CHANGEPCT24HOUR is the variable you're looking to output

There's also the issue of whether the API input is considered user input and how far you want to protect yourself against that, but I think that's another question/answer